# D (and Tango) on PowerPC Linux

Tags: linux, d, powerpc, tango

It's hard to search for D using Google, so I wasn't able to find a good answer:

I have an old iBook G3 and I'd like to install Linux on it and use it to compile (and test) D programs written using Tango on it. Is this possible? Or hasn't anybody tried it, yet? After all the Mac port of GDC + Tango is broken in parts, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This used to work, but it has been a combination with few users, and so I'm not sure if it has been tested recently. There shouldn't be major problems with Tango though - compiler is probably likely to a more likely issue. For that, you probably should try to compile your own from a recent SVN checkout (of GDC).